# dynamic binding

Tags: java

If a class implements an interface and have a `toString()` method 
and we store the child reference into parent variable or simply dynamic binding   is      done 
then why did not the compiler check the `toString()` method in interface because it is a rule of 
dynamic binding that function uniqueness will be check in parent

eg.

```
interface my {
    void show();
}

class child implements my {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("working");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "hello";
    }

    public static void main(String... s) {
        my m = new child();

        m.show();

        String s = m.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

We know that whenever dynamic binding is done child personal method cannot be executed unless it has overridden the above method 
so why above function `toString()` get complied and gives the output?

Comment: Please at least take the time to indent the code properly.

Comment: What are you asking?  A question should be short, without unnecessary distracting information.  Punctuation is not optional, it is required for anything in English to make sense.

Comment: You keep using *uniqueness* when I think you should talk about existence.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're asking this question:

*In my sample code, the local variable `m` has type `my`. The interface `my` only declares a single method, `show()`, so why am I able to call `m.toString()`?*

This is explained in the Sun (now Oracle) [Java tutorial on inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> > Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that are derived from classes, and so on, and **ultimately derived from the topmost class, Object.** Such a class is said to be descended from all the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.

[The `Object` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) declares a default `toString()` method (along with several other basic methods), therefore you can call `toString()` on *any* object in Java.

---

**Update**

Since all class instances in Java *must* inherit from Object, the actual semantics of using an interface as a type is something more like this:

```
public static void main(String... s) {
    // This won't actually compile
    (? extends Object implements my) m = new child(); 

    m.show();

    String s = m.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

In other words, when you declare that `m` has type `my` you're actually saying that `m` is some `Object` that implements the interface `my`. Since `Object` declares a `toString()` method, you're able to call `m.toString()` even though `toString()` isn't present in the `my` interface.

Java was purposely designed with `Object` at the top of the class hierarchy, so there's no way for you to get the compiler to complain about calling `toString()` on any instance of any object. The same goes for `hashCode()`, `equals()`, etc.

Comment: but the refernce variable is of interface then it should check the uniqueness in interface

Comment: If by *uniqueness* you mean *existence*, then you're right. I think what you're confused about is that `class child implements my` is actually the same thing as `class child extends Object implements my`. Since _all classes_ inherit from `Object`, the semantics of `my m` is actually something more like `<? extends Object implements my> m`.

Comment: Since the angle brackets `<>` usually denote generic type parameters in Java, using them that way might lead to some confusion. Just to be clear, `<? extends Object implements my> m` is _pseudocode_, so don't expect it to compile!

Comment: @user1658348 - I've updated my answer to elaborate on my comment, but I used parenthesis instead of angle brackets for my pseudo-type (@IgnisErus).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem will be resolved by the two answers already given.. I just want to point out a few things about your statement: -

- `if a class implements an interface and have a toString() method`

Any class you define has a `toString()` method.. Although it may not look obvious, but when you print an instance of your class, it is the `toString()` method of `Object` class which is invoked..(`Object` class is the super class of all other classes you define).. So, any method defined in `Object` class is accessible from any other `class object`.

You can either override this method to print your instance according to your need.. But, if not overrided, you will get a `hashcode` of your object..  (Something like: - `classname@12343`.. Now since this `toString()` method is available with all class, compiler don't need to check it in any `interface`.. It knows that `toString()` method is a part of `Object` class which is the `super class` of all classes..

- `we store the child reference into parent variable`

Although your understanding it right, but let me re-frame this sentence, to make it more meaninful: -  `We Store the reference to child class object in the parent class reference variable`

- `function uniqueness will be check in parent`

I really can't understand, what do you mean by this sentence.. But as far as I understand, you are saying that - "When a method of `child class` is called on a `parent class reference`, then compiler will check first, whether that method is defined in the `parent class` or not, then only you can call the method..

*** EDIT*** : -

According to [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2), Section 9.2: -

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature
>   s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public
>   instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t
>   declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly declares such a
>   method m in the case where m is declared to be final in Object.
>
> It follows that is a compile-time error if the interface declares a
>   method with a signature that is override-equivalent (§8.4.2) to a
>   public method of Object, but has a different return type or
>   incompatible throws clause.

Comment: @user1658348.. Is your doubt clear about `toString()` method?

Comment: "When a method of child class is called on a parent class reference, then compiler will check first, whether that method is defined in the parent class or not, then only you can call the method..  what about this??

Comment: @user1658348.. Suppose you have a `Parent` class reference pointing your `Child` class object.. Now you can only call those methods of `Child` class on this reference, which are defined in the `Parent` class... I thought you knew it??

Comment: yaa i knew it obviously thats what i am asking that it should check in the interface know but that method is not present

Answer (score 0):

All objects extend `Object`.  `public String toString()` is defined in `Object` so all Objects have a `toString()` method.

Comment: but reference variable is of interface

Comment: but it must be an `Object` regardless of the interface.

Comment: it means that durinfg dynamic binding function uniqueness is not checked in parent

Comment: Its the actual object, the method is called on.  The type of the reference doesn't matter as the interface doesn't have any method implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, it's because every non-primitive (primitives are `int`, `long`, etc; but NOT `String`) in Java has the type `Object`.  `Object` has the methods `toString()`, `hashCode()`, and `equals()`, which means that any non-primitive also has these methods.

However, these methods are usually too generic to be useful for specific classes, which is why we overload them whenever we need them.